# Adding multiple files with one PHP Call?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to add 2 different (html-header.php and header.php) files in one. I don't know PHP and most searches lead to advance code which I don't know.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

That includes one of my header files, how would I add another file that goes with header file. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using two `include` statements?

Comment: @Jasper, yeah... cause honestly I'm clueless when it comes to PHP.

Comment: @Jeff don't be afraid to try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include it, just like you included the first one. [Docs on include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'html-header.php';
?>
```

Include will just take whatever is in the file and substitute it for the `include 'file.php'` line. So the order in which you include files matters.

Comment: And if this is causing trouble somewhere along the way, you may want to use include_once to avoid any double includes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the include statement multiple times.

```
<?php
    include 'html-header.php';
    include 'header.php';
?>
```

Or if html-header ALWAYS goes with header, include an include line in header for html-header.php.

Comment: thank you for your help. Your suggestion of adding the header call in the html-header file was my DAMN...why'd I think of that moment of the day.